# Rails: redirect with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes, parameters

What's the best way to pass some params along with a redirect?

I saw examples that said if you just add them to your redirect hash they would pass along with the request, but that doesn't seem to work anymore in Rails 3.

In my example I have an 'edit multiple' page that lets a user change the category on multiple items at once. Because they're browsing so many items this form is paginated.

If a user is on `items page 3`, makes some changes and presses sumbit, then the controller action receives a post request with the ids of the records that were changed, makes the changes, and redirects to the `edit_many_items_path`.

So, that redirect looks like this:

```
redirect_to edit_multiple_items_path, :notice => 'items updated'
```

... but what I'd like it to do is something like:

```
redirect_to edit_multiple_items_path, :notice => 'items updated', :page => ##
```

The above code doesn't work, so does anyone have an example of what would?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this:

```
redirect_to(edit_multiple_items_path(:page =>2), :notice => 'items updated')
```

Comment: Yep, that did it! Of course it would, just pass the params through the URL... Why didn't I think of that!  Thanks!!!